# Postgres: order of `FOR UPDATE OF table` retrieval

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, database-locking

I'm wondering about data consistency when relying on `FOR UPDATE OF <table>` in a JOIN. I'll try to make a simple example:

Transaction 1 does:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE a.id = 5 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE b SET val = 'other' WHERE b.a_id = 5;
COMMIT;
```

Transaction 2 does this very closely after:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT b.val FROM a, b WHERE a.id = 5 AND b.a_id = 5 FOR UPDATE OF a;
[...]
```

Is there a chance that transaction 2 acquires the lock, but still gets an outdated `b.val`? The lock is on the row from `a` -- does it wait on that lock before retrieving the row from `b`?

Comment: Because of there is no lock in second transaction for table `b`, yes, there is chance you get    outdated `b.val`.

Comment: Yes, but only if transaction 1 hasn't committed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on the question confirm my suspicion -- the lock doesn't delay retrieval of other rows, from other tables. This is a pretty specific scenario, but I welcome informative answers showing easy ways to accomplish this. I ended up splitting the 2nd SELECT out into two queries -- the first SELECT obtains lock, and then a 2nd SELECT retrieves `b` rows, ensuring they are updated.